# Dyanamic Execution of javascript code

Tags: javascript

I have the following JavaScript:

```
var djs = function (ob) {

    return {
        remove: function () { //removes element
            if (is_array(ob)) {
                for (var i = 0; i < ob.length; i++) 
                    ob[i].parentNode.removeChild(ob[i]);
            } else {
                ob.parentNode.removeChild(ob);
            }
        },
        empty: function () { //makes element empty
            if (is_array(ob)) {
                for (var i = 0; i < ob.length; i++) 
                    ob[i].innerHTML = "";
            } else {
                ob.innerHTML = ""
            }
        },
        html: function (str) { //gets or sets innerHTML
            if (str) {
                if (is_array(ob)) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < ob.length; i++) 
                       ob[i].innerHTML = str;
                } else {
                    ob.innerHTML = str;
                }
            } else {
                if (is_array(ob)) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < ob.length; i++) 
                        rob += ob[i].innerHTML;
                    return rob;
                } else {
                    return ob.innerHTML;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here every time I am checking whether `ob` is an array or not and executing code. I want to minimize this, like instead of:

```
if (is_array(ob)) { 
    for (var i = 0; i < ob.length; i++) 
        ob[i].parentNode.removeChild(ob[i]);
} else { 
    ob.parentNode.removeChild(ob); 
}
```

I want to use a function like, `doEval(ob,code,return)`, in this case,

```
doEval(ob,"parentNode.removeChild("+ob+")",NULL);
```

"return" parameter will return if I specify any like `innerHTML`. Can any one help?

Comment: It seems you have a PHP accent

Comment: I think you could do this with a [higher-order function](http://spheredev.org/wiki/Higher-order_programming_in_JavaScript), but Javascript also has an [eval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp) function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't repeat `is_array` check:

```
var djs=function(ob) {
  if (!is_array(ob)) ob = [ob];
```

Answer (score 0):

@SHiNKiROU is right of course, but just to provide an example of how to solve your problem with higher-order functions:

```
function doToAll(ob, callback) {
    if(is_array(ob)) {
        for (var i = 0; i < ob.length; i++) {
            callback(ob[i]);
        }
    } else {
        callback(ob);
    }
}

...

remove:function(){ //removes element
    doToAll(ob, function(actualOb) { actualOb.parentNode.removeChild(actualOb); });
},
...
```

But again, use @SHiNKiROU:s answer for this particular case.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
function doEval(a, b, c) {
    if(is_array(a)) {
        eval(b);
    } else {
        eval(c);
    }
}
```

`NULL` doesn't exist by the way, it is `null`.